# Swagger UI with Swashbuckle not displaying OAuth2 option

Tags: oauth-2.0, swagger, swashbuckle

I've got a Web API which I've secured with OAuth2 but I'm having difficulty getting Swagger UI to show the authentication option.
Currently, the api_key section of UI still shows, despite there being no configuration for it.
Here's my SwaggerConfig

```
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        if (ConfigUtil.SSOSupported)
        {
            var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;
           // Swashbuckle.Application.OAuth2SchemeBuilder
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c =>
                    {

                        c.Schemes(new[] { "http", "https" });

                        c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "API Adapter");
                        c.PrettyPrint();

                        c.ApiKey(string.Empty);

                        c.OAuth2("oauth2")
                            .Description("Description here")
                            .Flow("implicit")
                            .AuthorizationUrl(ConfigUtil.SSOAuthority() + "/connect/authorize")
                            .Scopes(scopes =>
                            {
                                scopes.Add("api", "api");
                            });

                        c.IgnoreObsoleteProperties();

                        c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();
                    })
                .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                    {
                        c.EnableOAuth2Support("your-client-id", "your-client-secret-if-required", "your-realms", "your-app-name");
                    });
        }
    }
}
```

This section is included in page source after loading:

```
window.swashbuckleConfig = {
    rootUrl: 'http://localhost:44390',
    discoveryPaths: arrayFrom('swagger/docs/v1'),
    booleanValues: arrayFrom('true|false'),
    validatorUrl: stringOrNullFrom(''),
    customScripts: arrayFrom(''),
    docExpansion: 'none',
    supportedSubmitMethods: arrayFrom('get|put|post|delete|options|head|patch'),
    oAuth2Enabled: ('true' == 'true'),
    oAuth2ClientId: 'your-client-id',
    oAuth2ClientSecret: 'your-client-secret-if-required',
    oAuth2Realm: 'your-realms',
    oAuth2AppName: 'your-app-name',
    oAuth2ScopeSeperator: ' ',
    oAuth2AdditionalQueryStringParams: JSON.parse('{}'),
    apiKeyName: 'api_key',
    apiKeyIn: 'query'
  };
```

And the iniOAuth function is called:

```
window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
    url: swashbuckleConfig.rootUrl + "/" + swashbuckleConfig.discoveryPaths[0],
    dom_id: "swagger-ui-container",
    booleanValues: swashbuckleConfig.booleanValues,
    supportedSubmitMethods: swashbuckleConfig.supportedSubmitMethods,
    onComplete: function(swaggerApi, swaggerUi){
      if (typeof initOAuth == "function" && swashbuckleConfig.oAuth2Enabled) {
        initOAuth({
          clientId: swashbuckleConfig.oAuth2ClientId,
          clientSecret: swashbuckleConfig.oAuth2ClientSecret,
          realm: swashbuckleConfig.oAuth2Realm,
          appName: swashbuckleConfig.oAuth2AppName,
          scopeSeparator: swashbuckleConfig.oAuth2ScopeSeperator,
          additionalQueryStringParams: swashbuckleConfig.oAuth2AdditionalQueryStringParams
        });
```

But I just get the api_key text box and no Authorize button like I'd expect.

The controllers and actions all display without an issue.

I'm sure it's something small, but I've been fiddling for a couple of days now and have run out of ideas.

Comment: Which Swashbuckle version and [Swagger UI version](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/version-detection.md) are you using? It's most likely an old UI version without OAuth 2 support.

Comment: I'm using Swashbuckle.Core 5.6.0, I'll try the latest one but I think there was a dependency that wasn't compatible with the rest of the solution which is why i didn't use it initially ...

Comment: Can you post a link to your swagger.json it should be something like: http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/V1